# add object if only it doesn't already exists (Embedded Forms) Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I need some help. I have a form that adds a medical record, which is linked to the entity patient by a manyToOne relationship.

MedicalRecordType.php

```
class MedicalRecordType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
            {
                  $builder->add('service','text');
                  $builder->add('patient','collection', array('type' => new PatientType()));
                  $builder->add('piece','collection', array('type' => new PieceType()));
            } 
}
```

PatientType.php

```
class PatientType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

         $builder
                ->add('Firstname', 'text')
                ->add('Secondname', 'text')
                ->add('DateOfBirth', 'date', array(
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                ))
        ;
    }
```

when adding a new medical record, I do not want to add Patient data along with it if a patient already exists in the database. Thanks for any suggestions.

i'm aware that i can do this with a simple condition in the controller, but it's gonna take a lot of code, i was wondering if there is an easier way with symfony.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to do, could you rephrase that a little ? And maybe show the Entities behind the forms ? Also, in your MedicalRecordType, you can write : 
    $builder->add('patient', new PatientType());

Comment: check my post now, i've edited it! thanx in advance!

Comment: There's is no way to tell Symfony Form to check entity existance before mapping. It just maps request data to an object. You should manually check that before persisting the handled entity. You can write a service for it if you dont want your controllers become fat.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a [oneToMany](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) relationship in your entities:
One MedicalReport holds many Patient entities.
Than you can do something like this in your form-builder:

```
$builder->add('patients','entity', array(
   'class' => 'YourBundle:Patient',
));
```

and if your entity mapping is correct doctrine will automatically insert or update the needed rows